# Firebase : Cannot create a project in Firebase. " There was an unknown error while creating the project. Try again. "

Tags: firebase

I'am trying to create a add project in Firebase but i get this message: " There was an unknown error while creating the project. Try again. "

Please can anyone help me?

[Error message creating project in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMOsX.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because support requests should go directly to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 2):

There is a [known problem with new project creation](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/19014).  See the Firebase status dashboard for more information.  In the future, contact Firebase support directly with experiencing problem with the Firebase console.